# Java JSON Apache POST Parameters

Tags: java, json, apache, http, post

So I've got this code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("url");
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity("stuff");
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        //request.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        //stuff
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //stuff
    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

I need to create a POST request which I can do with curl -X POST /groups/:group_id/members/add etc but I'm not sure how to add the /groups/ param to my code... I'm not super familiar with how to do this so any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT 1: (SOLVED)
Have used the suggested code but would like some help with variables used in the string while remaining valid JSON format, if possible.

EDIT 2:
Using that method, can you show an example of how to add multiple users to that one StringEntity? So like user1 is "User1" and has the email "Email1" and user2 has "User2" and "Email2" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a url string using the prams you have and pass it as argument to HttpPost()

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String groupId = "groupId1";
     String URL = "http://localhost:8080/"+groupId+"/members/add"
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
           URL );

    StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"name\":matt,\"from\":\"stackovefflow\"}");
    input.setContentType("application/json");
    postRequest.setEntity(input);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

**UPDATED**

The input to StringEntity is a string whihc you can manipulate in any way.

You can define a method like

```
private createStringEntity(String name, String email){
            return new StringEntity("{\"name\":\""+name+"\",\"email\":\""+email+"\"}");
        }
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a variable in the StringEntity input? The goal is to automate the adding of users to a group via this http request, so it'll be in a loop and the value of the fields (name, email) will be variables.

Comment: Is there a way to add multiple users to that one StringEntity? See edit2 in main post

Comment: Loop over your user list and call this method passing in the corresponding users params

Answer (score 0):

The "/groups/..." part is not a parameter but a fraction of the url. I dont think this will work, because "url" is just a String, change it to this:

```
 HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://stackoverflow.com/groups/[ID]/members/add");
```

Comment: So, say my url is stackoverflow.com - it would be  http://stackoverflow.com/groups/id/members/add and then just go through the rest of the code as normal?